# c#, скриншот, обрезка скриншота

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap memoryImage;
    Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    Size s = this.Size;
    memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width - 95, s.Height - 10, myGraphics);
    Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);      
    memoryImage.Save("C:\\Users\\valav\\source\\repos\\Schedule v2.5\\printscreen.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);              
}
```

Есть вот такой вот код, он делает скрин формы, как мне можно обрезать скрин, если есть не нужные детали слева/сверху

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, конкретизируйте вопрос

Comment: Как обрезать скриншот который делается при нажатии на кнопку, что бы убрать область которая обрезана красными линиям (область слева/область сверху)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно скришот, можно любой контрол отрисовать в битмап

```
private Bitmap DrawControlToBitmap(Control control)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);
    control.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, control.Size));
    return bmp;
}
```

Для формы будет так

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = DrawControlToBitmap(this);
    bmp.Save("image.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Если нужно не всю форму, а какую-то панель, просто вместо `this` передайте аргументом нужный контрол, например панель, в которой размещена нужная группа контролов.

Если ваши текстбоксы не в панели, а просто разбросаны по форме, создайте такую панель и перенесите контролы в неё.

---

Если не знакомы, то обязательно познакомьтесь с `FlowLayoutPanel` и `TableLayoutPanel`, они помогут с позиционированием.

Comment: а как теперь этот bmp сохранить как png или Jpeg файл?

Comment: или как вывести на печать на принтере?

Comment: @DersKOTz да, просто сохраните в файл или распечатайте https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247886/12888024

Comment: Вроде вставил перед return bmp;
bmp.Save("C:\\Users\\valav\\source\\repos\\Schedule v2.5\\abb.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);      
а оно не сохраняет

Comment: @DersKOTz Не надо писать ничего в методе, который я дал. Он уже полностью написан. Получайте битмап из него и используйте там, где получили. И я не понимаю значения слов "не сохраняется".

Comment: ну вот я получил битмап и хочу его сохранить например на диск С, как мне это сделать?

Comment: @DersKOTz дописал код в ответе, обновите страницу.

Comment: вроде всё делаю правильно но оно не сохраняет, пример кода добавил в вопрос

Comment: @DersKOTz я даже не ожидал что с этим будут сложности, еще раз дописал код.

Comment: Спасибо большое, да я не силен в c#, очень сильно выручили, огромная благодарность!

Comment: @DersKOTz ура, вот, позанимайтесь, очень полезные видео https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ

Comment: Спасибо))))))))))