# Как распечатать картинку на принтере?

Tags: c#, winforms, печать

Как печатать обычный текст на принтере я понял, а как печатать картинку например расположенную по адресу C:\Users\valav\source\repos\Schedule v2.6\Scheduleprint.jpg я не совсем понимаю, подскажите как можно распечатать картинку на принтере?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489022/220553

Comment: А если мне для WinForm?

Comment: Надо метку `winforms` ставить на вопрос значит

Comment: Я вам в комментах к прошлому вопросу уже давал ссылку на ответ про печать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1507964/373567 - внимательнее надо быть

Comment: извиняюсь, забыл :)

Comment: "А если мне для WinForm?" - внимательно читайте, там написано "Решение для WinForms + консоль (GDI) Вынесено в отдельный вопрос".

Comment: Решил проблему, спасибо!